# node-opencv npm - will it do multithreaded calculations even though node is single threaded?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, opencv, computer-vision

Can a node.js implementation of openCV exploit multithreaded capable hosts and/or Nvidida GPUs?

I'm new to Node JS and noticed there is are openCV bindings.

I've done a little bit of openCV for a uni project and was interested in using node.js for image processing.

Node is single threaded and I believe openCV leverages multicores especially if they are Nvidia GPUs?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single threaded, nodejs is not. There are nodejs bindings to the OpenCV C++ library, meaning you basically get all the performance benefits of OpenCV, just use it with a Javascript API.

You get multithreading out of it, if the bindings provide async methods via AsyncWorkers. You can give my npm package [opencv4nodejs](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs) a try, which provides an async API, that makes multithreading pretty simple via Promises.

For GPU acceleration OpenCV has different modules, with a seperate API, as you probably know. In case you wanted to use this API with nodejs, one would have to come up with bindings for that as well.

Comment: GPU acceleration requires different modules?  Sorry I'm a newbie. How do I get that going in general?  Any good links? …how come you don't have bindings for the GPU version?

Comment: Yes, for example see the cuda modules here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/. There are no bindings for that since I did not add them (yet) and I am not that familar with opencv cuda.